# How can I avoid duplicates when copying data with a VBA script?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm completely new to VBA and am currently trying to write a script that copies data from one Excel sheet into another if the conditions are met. Its working mostly okay but if I add data to the mastersheet and run the script again I end up with duplicates.

```
Sub Test()
lastrow = Worksheets("Test1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For r = 2 To lastrow
If Worksheets("Test1").Range("F" & r).Value = "e" And Worksheets("Test1").Range("A:F").Interior.Color = Green Then
Worksheets("Test1").Range("A" & r & ":B" & r & ",E" & r).Copy

Worksheets("Test2").Activate
lastRowRpt = Worksheets("Test2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Test2").Range("A" & lastRowRpt + 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

    End If

Next r
End Sub
```

Another problem I'm having is with the background color condition: If any row in my table has a green background ALL the rows that meet the first condition will be pasted even if the second condition is not met. It would be nice to get a fix for that too but its not as important as the first problem since this is just to reduce the chance of accidentally pasting the wrong data.

I tried to look up ways to avoid the duplicates and while there were many threads none of them were particularly useful to me since their code was quite different and since I am new to this I could not figure out how to implement the solutions into my code.

For the color problem I tried adding the & r that I used in other parts of the code as well but then nothing got pasted at all.

Comment: Where is the unique key? In the A-column, A-column combined with something else or A to F? Does the entire Range need to have the background color green? "Green" isn't checked this way, depending on what color the user picked, you'd be better off checking first what specific green the person chose with `Debug.Print Range("rangewithyourcolor").Interior.Color`

Comment: It's supposed to be A-F I want the program to check for the "e" in the F-column and then see if the row in which the e also has the green background color as the table i'm actually writing the script for is pretty big and you can lose your place quickly so we use the green background color plus the 'e' to show that the case is closed. Also i went with just green over a rgb code or something of the sort as we just use the default green that excel offers anyway

Comment: "just green" doesn't exist, the light green that's pre-set for standard excel is "5296274", there's also `vbGreen` but that's so flashy that it makes the light green I usually use to look mossy; so best to check prior that it's the same green (or have a header with that color so you can pass that one to a variable to compare to). Was the "It's supposed to be A-F" the answer to what makes your row unique? (That was your original question, to avoid duplicates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to avoid duplication is to mark rows had been copied already:

```
With Worksheets("Test1")
    If .Range("F" & r).Value = "e" And .Range("A:F").Interior.Color = Green And .Cells(r, "G") <> 1 Then
        .Cells(r, "G") = 1
        .Range("A" & r & ":B" & r & ",E" & r).Copy
        ...
    End If
End With
```

Use any available column instead of "G".

Comment: Did the solution help?

Comment: yup worked great thx!

Comment: Can you accept my answer?

Comment: ofc sorry i'm new to this site so I didn't know about this feature yet!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to filter your data, copy the visible cells to the next sheet and then remove duplicates.
Note - the RGB values will probably need updating.

```
Sub Test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test1")
    
        'Turn any existing filters off.
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
            
        'The range containing data.
        Dim RangeToCopy1 As Range
        Set RangeToCopy1 = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, 6))
            
        'Filter to "e" and green.
        With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, 6))
            .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="e"
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(0, 176, 80), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
            
            'Set reference to the visible cells.
            Dim RangeToCopy As Range
            Set RangeToCopy = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        End With
    
    End With
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test2")
    
        'Copy and paste to Test2 - this will copy formatting, formula, etc.
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        RangeToCopy.Copy Destination:=.Cells(LastRow, 1)
        
        'Figure out where the new last row is.
        LastRow = LastRow + RangeToCopy.Rows.Count + 1
        
        'Remove duplicates.
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 6)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Header:=xlYes
    End With

End Sub
```